# Xcode preview crashes on DB loop read SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

When I call Core Data using:

```
 @FetchRequest(
        entity: Entity.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Entity.id, ascending: true),
        ]
    )  var myData: FetchedResults<Entity>
```

then inside the View:

```
VStack {
    ForEach(myData, id: \.self) { data in
        Text("Test")
    }
}
```

Xcode live preview crashes, if I remove the ForEach with a simple text it would work, how can I fix this? This is my current preview:

```
struct HomeItemListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeItemListView()
    }
}
```

This is the error it shows:

```
PotentialCrashError: MyApp.app may have crashed

MyApp.app may have crashed. Check ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports for any crash logs from your application.

==================================

|  Error Domain=com.apple.dt.ultraviolet.service Code=12 "Rendering service was interrupted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Rendering service was interrupted}
```

As side note, the code compiles fine and displays fine on the normal simulator, it's the live one that has issues.

**UPDATE:**
So I have a viewRouter that controls the first screen, example Onboarding, if true, it goes to onboarding, if false it goes to HomeView.
This is how I have setup SceneDelegate:

```
let viewRouter = ViewRouter()

        let contentView = MotherView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
            .environmentObject(viewRouter)

            // Set the MotherView as the root view
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
```

On my MotherView, I have the Preview like this:

```
struct MotherView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MotherView().environmentObject(ViewRouter())
    }
}
```

And on the Home view I have it like this:

```
struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Most probably either context environment or some environmentObject is not set.

Comment: How can I check that? In SceneDelegate? @Asperi

Comment: for preview (in preview provider) you should set up everything in the same way as you do in scene delegate for run-time (if it is root view, as as it set up in parent if it is child view)

Comment: I updated the code above and added some more information such as SceneDelegate, would that help? @Asperi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, most probably, your `HomeItemListView` preview should be set as follows

```
struct HomeItemListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        return HomeItemListView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
                .environmentObject(ViewRouter())
    }
}
```